# How to dynamically change the background color of a Leaflet Divicon Marker in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a JS script in which I recursively add markers on a Map using leaflet library. For doing this I use the following function:

```js
function showMarker(key){
    
    markerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < N_staz; i++){
        
        var value = data[key][i];
        
        var myIcon = L.divIcon({
                iconSize: [30, 20],
                className: 'MarkerClass',
                html:'<b>'+value+'</b>'
        });
        
        L.marker([data["latitude"][i],data["longitude"][i]], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(markerGroup);
        
    } 
}
```

I just pass the key (which could be for example "temperature") and it adds `N_staz` markers with the temperature values stored in the `data` array.
The problem is that with `L.divIcon` I can pass a css class for the marker and cannot pass directly the properties such as the background color. Anyway, I would assign a different color to each marker by the temperature value. So I wrote a function (`Temp2Color`) which takes the temperature value and returns a color in hex format (e.g. `Temp2Color(30)` returns `#f6ff00`). So I have the color I want for each marker, but I don't know how to assign it to them, because I can just pass a css class.

Because the color scale I am using in the function `Temp2Color` is continuous, I can't create a css class for each color!

What can I do so? Can I modify dynamically the css class `MarkerClass`, or in some way pass to `L.divIcon` directly the color I want?

Comment: Is this not possible to add "style", same as of "className"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaflet changing Marker color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567203/leaflet-changing-marker-color)