# Custom Leaflet markers when markers are coded as a layer, not built individually?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet map adapted from [this tutorial](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/#rendering-markers-incrementally) builds markers like:

```js
async function render_markers() {
const markers = await load_markers();
L.geoJSON(markers)
    .bindPopup((layer) => layer.feature.properties.name)
    .addTo(layerGroup);
}
```

I want to change this map's markers to any of the solutions recommended in [this good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870439/4107349). But I don't know how to get a handle on them as all markers seem built individually, eg:

```js
L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

[Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) also only seems to show how to change markers individually. How can we get a [solution like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870439) working with the way our map is built? What are we missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for this [Leaflet-Tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

To customize markers or circles you need to add `pointToLayer` function:

```
L.geoJSON(markers, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: greenIcon} );
    }
})
    .bindPopup((layer) => layer.feature.properties.name)
    .addTo(layerGroup);
```